# invalid or unknown key: network_security_group_id

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Here is my code block for creating the network interface and attaching security group in Azure with Terrfaorm. I have used the same in another module but I'm getting an error when running this:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "myterraformnic" {
  name                      = "${var.vm_name}-nic"
  location                  = "${azurerm_resource_group.sdsterraformgroup.location}"
  resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.sdsterraformgroup.name}"
  network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.myterraformnsg.id}"
}
```

Here is the error I get when I run a plan or an apply.:

```
**"Error: azurerm_network_interface.myterraformnic: : invalid or unknown key: network_security_group_id"**
```

Comment: The [`azurerm_network_interface resource`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/network_interface.html) does not have a `network_security_group_id` parameter. Where were you using that parameter before?

Comment: Do you solve the problem with the answer? If it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 4):

**azurerm_network_interface** resource in terraform does not have a **network_security_group_id** paramter.

If you are trying to associate network security group with a network interface, make change to terraform resource block as below

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "myterraformnic" {
  name                      = "${var.vm_name}-nic"
  location                  = "${azurerm_resource_group.sdsterraformgroup.location}"
  resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.sdsterraformgroup.name}"
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "example" {
  network_interface_id      = azurerm_network_interface.myterraformnic.id
  network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.myterraformnsg.id}"
}
```

By changing template as above, "**azurerm_network_interface**" resource block will create network interface and network security group will be associated to network interface in "**azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association**" resource block

Comment: In addition to this answer. This parameter was there in older versions of `azurerm`. It has been removed atleast after 2.0.0.